# structural navigation not updating

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation

I am able to delete and edit headings and link but when i navigate back to the navigation on the homepage  it is still the same. I went back to the structural navigation settings to find out that none of my modification are being saved

i am the owner of the site and it is a classic experience. at the site collection level the publishing feature is activated but at the site level when i try to do it,it give me an error

Answer (score 0):

What’s the permission of the account who want edit the navigation? Make sure the user is owner or has edit permissions in the site level.

Whether you encounter this issue in Modern experience or Classic experience?

Have you enabled publishing feature? You can check the article to get more information about [Customize the navigation on your SharePoint site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca)

Comment: i am the owner of the site and it is a classic experience. at the site collection level the publishing feature is activated but at the site level when i try to do it,it give me an error